# Appium - Could not start a new session on iPad

Tags: java, ios, ipad, automation, appium

I am trying to automate iOS app on real iPad device. My code was working fine till last week and suddenly started throwing error from today. Neither `Xcode`, `nodejs`, `java` or `Appium` has been upgraded. No code has been updated whatsoever.

```
public AppiumDriver runOnRealDevice() {
        try {
            XCUITestOptions options = new XCUITestOptions();
            options.setDeviceName("my iPad");
            options.setPlatformVersion("16.5.1");
            options.setWdaLaunchTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
            options.setCapability("xcodeOrgId","......");
            options.setCapability("xcodeSigningId","iPhone Developer");
            options.setCapability("udid","......");
            driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"),options);
            
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("bundleId", "com.myapplebundleidentfier");
            driver.executeScript("mobile:launchApp",params);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Here12 "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

The issue happens on `driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"),options);`

Below is the complete error message

```
StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: '-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1044:a4fe:6300:fc53%en0'
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.4.1', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:udid=myudid, appium:xcodeOrgId=myxoceorgid, appium:wdaLaunchTimeout=20000, appium:xcodeSigningId=iPhone Developer, appium:deviceName=iPad, platformName=IOS, appium:automationName=XCuiTest, appium:platformVersion=16.5.1}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:automationName: XCuiTest, appium:deviceName: Pritish’s iPad, appium:platformVersion: 16.5.1, appium:udid:dsssddsdssd, appium:wdaLaunchTimeout: 20000, appium:xcodeOrgId: dsdsdsdsdssd, appium:xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer, platformName: IOS}}]
Capabilities {appium:automationName: XCuiTest, appium:deviceName: my iPad, appium:platformVersion: 16.5.1, appium:udid: sddsdsdsds, appium:wdaLaunchTimeout: 20000, appium:xcodeOrgId: ddsds, appium:xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer, platformName: IOS}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:536)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:106)
    at WebPortal.IOSBaseTest.runOnRealDevice(IOSBaseTest.java:66)
    at WebPortal.IOSBaseTest.setup(IOSBaseTest.java:32)
    at WebPortal.IOSBaseTest.getDriver(IOSBaseTest.java:25)
    at stepDefinitions.TA124_ComprehensiveCI_StepDefinitions.<init>(TA124_ComprehensiveCI_StepDefinitions.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ObjectFactoryServiceLoader$DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.java:141)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ObjectFactoryServiceLoader$DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.java:133)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:104)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:73)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$5(Runtime.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:117)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toJson(java.lang.Object, int)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:105)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:194)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue by removing following dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Well done, that should work indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include possible reasons for that fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toJson(java.lang.Object, int)'
```

That should mean your code, or one of the libraries you are using, is trying to call a method that does not exist in the version of the library that is currently loaded. It is common to see this error when there are mismatches in library versions.

Since you have not changed your code, and the versions of Appium and other tools are the same, it is possible that you might have inadvertently updated some libraries. Check if your project's dependencies (libraries/jars) are consistent and compatible.

- If you are using Maven, check your `pom.xml` file.
- If you are using Gradle, check your `build.gradle` file.

If your project source code with using Git, a `git status` should help visualize any change.

Make sure the versions of Appium's Java client and Selenium's Java client are compatible.

Try and clear the cache and reinstall dependencies.

- If using Maven:

```bash
mvn clean install
```

- If using Gradle:

```bash
./gradlew clean build
```

If you are only specifying the [Appium Java client](https://github.com/appium/java-client) in your dependency management tool, try explicitly specifying a compatible Selenium version too (See [Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/appium/java-client#compatibility-matrix)). Appium's client has a dependency on Selenium, and there might be compatibility issues between versions.

Check also if your device's OS version was updated, it might affect Appium's behavior.

---

The OP mentions having resolved the issue by removing:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-4</version>
</dependency>
```

The `selenium-devtools` dependency is specific to Chrome and the Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP). It provides capabilities to interact with Chrome's DevTools for advanced automation tasks that go beyond the standard Selenium capabilities. Examples include manipulating network conditions, setting breakpoints, etc.

The OP was using version `4.0.0-beta-4`. If your other Selenium dependencies were not of the same version, it might have caused conflicts.

And the `selenium-devtools` artifact might have pulled in transitive dependencies that conflicted with other dependencies in your project.

Given the OP's stack trace showed issues with iOS testing (`io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver`), the Chrome-specific `selenium-devtools` dependency might not have been necessary. Appium iOS testing does not utilize Chrome DevTools.

Since Java libraries sometimes have classes with the same names, it is possible the `selenium-devtools` dependency introduced classes that conflicted with others on the classpath.

Comment: Same kind of error on [`appium/java-client issue 1980`](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1980).

Comment: Thanks I have checked multiple times. I have not touched pom.xml, neither my os has been upgraded. When I try to connect via appium inspector it works but issue arises for mobile automation.

Comment: @BraveEvidence What a `mvn dependency:tree` shows you? Is there multiple versions of the same library or related libraries? Specifically, check for different versions of Selenium libraries.  Maven might update transitive dependencies without an explicit command from you.

Comment: @BraveEvidence Also, if there was a software update on your iPad (even minor ones or automatic ones in the background), the version you specified in your script might no longer match the device's version. It is possible that other settings or configurations on the device changed, causing the session creation to fail.

Comment: @BraveEvidence Or, even if you have not upgraded anything, the version of the Appium server you are running might have some issues with the Java client version you are using.  If there is an auto-update mechanism in place (or if another team member changed versions without your knowledge), there could be a sudden misalignment between the Appium server and the Java client.

Comment: It's just me on my team. My last commit to my bitbucket branch was five weeks ago and the issue started happening from this week. As far as I know nothing is on auto update option

Comment: my software update for both Macos and iOS is off for automatic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254892/discussion-between-braveevidence-and-vonc).