# Could not start a new session appium

Tags: session, appium

https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1980

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
[Configuration] [WARN] Detected a static method [BaseTR.TestEngineTR.startSuite()]. Static configuration methods can cause  unexpected behavior.
Aug 17, 2023 4:32:05 PM BaseTR.TestEngineTR startSuite
INFO: Properties file loaded successfully
Aug 17, 2023 4:32:05 PM BaseTR.TestEngineTR startSuite
INFO: Intializing extent Reports
Aug 17, 2023 4:32:05 PM BaseTR.TestEngineTR startSuite
INFO: Extent report is available under the same directoryC:\Users\subhashini_r\eclipse-workspace\DemoNewPOM\Reports\testReport.html
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[35m[Appium][39m Welcome to Appium v2.0.0-beta.66
[35m[Appium][39m Non-default server args:
[35m[Appium][39m { address: [32m'127.0.0.1'[39m, localTimezone: [33mtrue[39m }
[35m[Appium][39m Attempting to load driver uiautomator2...
[debug] [35m[Appium][39m Requiring driver at C:\Users\\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver
[35m[Appium][39m Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
[35m[Appium][39m Available drivers:
[35m[Appium][39m   - uiautomator2@2.18.0 (automationName 'UiAutomator2')
[35m[Appium][39m No plugins have been installed. Use the "appium plugin" command to install the one(s) you want to use.
[38;5;0m[HTTP][0m [37m-->[39m [37mGET[39m [37m/status[39m
[38;5;0m[HTTP][0m [90m{}[39m
[debug] [38;5;16m[AppiumDriver@da8a][0m Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [38;5;16m[AppiumDriver@da8a][0m Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"2.0.0-beta.66"}}
[38;5;0m[HTTP][0m [37m<-- GET /status [39m[32m200[39m [90m5 ms - 47[39m
[38;5;0m[HTTP][0m [90m[39m
FAILED: configureAppium
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: '', ip: ''
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:deviceName="Pixel2API33", platformName=ANDROID, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:app=C:\Users\subhashini_r\eclipse-workspace\DemoNewPOM\src\test\resources\General-Store.apk}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:app: C:\Users\sc\eclip..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: "Pixel2API33", platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {appium:app: C:\Users\s\eclip..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: "Pixel2API33", platformName: ANDROID}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:536)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:113)
    at BaseTR.TestEngineTR.configureAppium(TestEngineTR.java:211)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toJson(java.lang.Object, int)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:105)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    ... 32 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I tried to change the port and found this https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1980 and your comments on the post. This is not working , I saw ur blog which posted some discussion on similar terms. Please help.

Please let me know if this is now resolved

@Voc

Comment: @Vonc Posted this , please let me know if you have any resolution for this

Comment: @VonC if you have any solution please let me know

Comment: @BraveEvidence if you have any solution to this please let me know

Comment: I found a solution and I updated all the pom.xl it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question (from this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76864429/6309)). What did you update in your pom.xml, to make it work?